# Как указать переменную в Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)

    with open ('C:расположение', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    async def update_data(users,user):
        if not user in users:
            users[user] = {}
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = 1
    async def add_exp(users,user,exp):
        users[user]['exp'] += exp
    async def add_lvl(users, user):
        pls = users [user]['exp']
        vls = users [user]['lvl']
        if pls > vls:
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}LVL UP!')
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = vls + 1

            
             
    await update_data(users, str(message.author.id))
    await add_exp(users,str(message.author.id),0.1)
    await add_lvl(users,str(message.author.id))
#await вызывает функцию
    with open ('C:\расположение ', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

Я хочу, чтобы после LVL UP шла пременная vls. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}LVL UP {vls}!')
```

Если я правильно вас понимаю